# preg_replace problems

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a string The Incredible Hulk (2008) and use pattern

```
/^\([0-9]{1,4}\)$/
```

to remove (2008). PHP code looks like this:

```
$x = trim(preg_replace("/^\([0-9]{1,4}\)$/", "", "The Incredible Hulk (2008)"));
```

And the result is:

```
The Incredible Hulk (2008)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the `^` character that matches start of line. Remove that and it should work.

If you also want to get rid of the whitespace before the `(` the regex becomes `/\s*\([0-9]{1,4}\)$/`

Answer (score 2):

Take out "^".

```
$x = trim(preg_replace("/\([0-9]{1,4}\)$/", "", "The Incredible Hulk (2008)"));
```

The (2008) is not anchored at the start of the string. "^" requires the match to start at the beginning of a line.

Answer (score 1):

`^` and `$` are mark begin and end of the entire string. Remove both.

```
$x = trim(preg_replace("/\([0-9]{4}\)/", "", "The Incredible Hulk (2008)"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `^` sign (beginning of line).

```
$x = trim(preg_replace("/\([0-9]{1,4}\)$/", "", "The Incredible Hulk (2008)"));
```

(you might want to remove the `$` sign as well (end of line))

More info about PHP meta characters in the documentation:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = preg_replace('/\([\d]{4}\)$/', '', 'The Incredible Hulk (2008)');
```